# Asp.net development server as web server

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to configure asp.net development server to be web server at 80 port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the inbuilt web server from VS, no, however if you violently object to using IIS, you can download Cassini (for .NET <= 3.5) or the updated server from [here](http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I thought that is possible.